# Fatal Exception: iOS app Crashes due toOpenGL rendering while app in background state

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

My flutter app reporting the following crashes on firebase Crashlytics related to OpenGL rendering problem. This problem occurred only in iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus.

tried on flutter chat community but did not get any reply.

I have posted my issue on git but did not get any reply.
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37478